# Algorithm for finding subsets

Tags: python-3.x

Algorithm for finding subsets. This program outputs empty lists, since it most likely takes the global variable 'subset'. How to take a local variable 'subset' and add it to the list?

```
subsets = []
subset = []

n = int(input())
k = int(input())

def search(k):
    if k == n+1:
        subsets.append(subset)
    else:
        subset.append(k)
        search(k+1)
        subset.pop()
        search(k+1)

search(k)
print(subsets)
```

Comment: please add the expected and actual output

Comment: let's say you want to enter the list `subsets` inside another list `x`, then you will use this: `x.append(subsets)`, then your list would look like this: `[[]]`

Comment: n = 1
k = 3

excepted output: [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2], [1, 3], [1], [2, 3], [2], [3], []]
actual output: [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `subset` as a parameter, or else the global variable will be used.

```
def search(k, subset):
    if k == n+1:
        subsets.append(subset)
    else:
        subset.append(k)
        search(k+1, subset)
        subset.pop()
        search(k+1, subset)
```

Comment: Understood. Thanks

Comment: If that solves the purpose, consider marking this as the accepted answer